# Combining style options for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply some style settings to a pandas dataframe. I have been able to apply those separatly, but I can't figure out how to combine them.

I would like the cell with the highest value to be highlighted in lightgreen for each row, and I have been able to do this by using

```
df.style.highlight_max(axis=1, props='background-color:lightgreen;', subset=['p_1', 'p_X', 'p_2'])
```

At the same time, I'd like to highlight specific rows (in a list) in yellow, like this:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: yellow' if x.name in confirmed else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

As last option, I'd like to show only the first three decimals of floats:

```
df.style.format('{:.3f}')
```

How can I combine these options?

Comment: Take a look at @Eyal Trabelsi's [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/style-pandas-dataframe-like-a-master-6b02bf6468b0) about using/combining multiple style for a dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried to chain them one by one `df.style.highlight_max(...).apply(...).format(...)`?

Comment: the above comments help. You basically need to understand that everytime you call `df.style` you are creating a new object (with no knowledge of your previous calls). Just save it to a variable: `styler = df.style` and then add further methods to `styler`